# Does QT_NO_DEBUG cause a definition of NDEBUG?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm auditing some source code written with the Qt framework. A typical release build command line output includes `QT_NO_DEBUG` preprocessor macro, but does *not* include Posix's `NDEBUG` preprocessor macro. The Qt [documentation on `QT_NO_DEBUG`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/debug.html) does not discuss `NDEBUG` (I may not have found the correct documentation, btw).

Does Qt's `QT_NO_DEBUG` cause a definition of Posix's `NDEBUG`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Add

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): DEFINES += NDEBUG
```

to your `.pro` file and a test like

```
{
    bool valuesEqual = false;

#ifdef NDEBUG
#ifdef QT_NO_DEBUG
    valuesEqual = true;
#endif
#endif

#ifndef NDEBUG
#ifndef QT_NO_DEBUG
    valuesEqual = true;
#endif
#endif

    EXPECT_TRUE(valuesEqual);
}
```